# Laravel - отношения Many To Many и создание связи при сохранении записи

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Есть 2 модели - авторы и книги, а также промежуточная таблица для их связи. Прошу знатоков посмотреть на запрос на добавление и сказать, обязательно ли делать такие телодвижения с `foreach` или это можно сделать как-то проще и/или правильнее.

Модель книг:

```
class Books extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'books';
  protected $fillable = ['title', 'year_of_publishing'];

  public function authors()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\models\Authors::class, 'authors_books', 'authors_id', 'books_id');
  }
}
```

Модель авторов:

```
class Authors extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'authors';
  protected $fillable = ['author'];

  function books()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\models\Books::class, 'authors_books', 'books_id', 'authors_id');
  }
}
```

Миграция для промежуточной таблицы:

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::create('authors_books', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('books_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->integer('authors_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->unique(['authors_id', 'books_id']);
    $table->foreign('authors_id')->references('id')->on('authors');
    $table->foreign('books_id')->references('id')->on('books');
  });
}
```

Форма добавления:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('books.store')}}">
  @csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Название книги</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="title" name="title">
    <label for="year_of_publishing">Год издания</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="year_of_publishing" name="year_of_publishing">
    <label for="authors[]">Выберите автора(ов)</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" name="authors[]">
      @foreach($authors as $author)
      <option value="{{$author->id}}">{{$author->author}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
</form>
```

Контроллер и собственно сам код запроса на добавление:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $item = new Books();
  $data = $request->All();
  $item->fill($data)->save();
  $lastAdded = Books::all()->last()->id;
  foreach ($data['authors'] as $author) {
    $item->authors()->attach($lastAdded, ['books_id' => $lastAdded, 'authors_id' => $author]);
  }
}
```

В результате этого, записи появляются как в таблице книг так и в промежуточной. То есть всё вроде как работает, но в идеале это бы сделать одним запросом. Чтобы сделать одним запросом, пробовал вместо `$lastAdded` и `$author` передавать массивы вот так:

```
 $bind = array_fill(0, count($data['authors']), $lastAdded);
 $item->authors()->attach($lastAdded,['books_id'=>$bind, 'authors_id'=>$data['authors']]);
```

На что Laravel вполне резонно отвечал мне, что ожидает там строку.

Ещё вопрос по поводу этих строк, где я сначала добавляю запись в таблицу книги а потом достаю её `id` и использую его для добавления уже в промежуточную таблицу. Это нормально, или нужно делать как-то по другому?

```
$item->fill($data)->save();
$lastAdded = Books::all()->last()->id;
```

Comment: По поводу именований, я сначала сделал, и уже потом узнал что так делать не нужно. В дальнейшем буду использовать правильные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы уже сходу не следуете конвенции именования таблиц и столбцов в таблицах, все остальное уже нормально. Таблицы во множественном числе (books). Внутри столбец id. В связанных таблицах book_id - имя таблицы в единственном и id в конце. Таблицы многие ко многим именуются в единственном числе по именам связанных таблицы. И при этом первее идёт имя по алфавиту. Тогда в моделях не нужно указывать море лишнего. Модели именуются в единственном числе.

всё, что есть по аттачам есть в документации - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

если всё сделать правильно, то получится вот так

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $book = new Book();
    $book->fill($request->all())->save();
    $book->authors()->attach($request->authors); // при условии, что authors это уже массив с id, иначе id нужно сначала получить (Arr::pluck(), например)
}
```

Согласно документации можно добавить сразу несколько значений, если передать их как массив. book_id подставляется автоматически, т.к. мы к нему аттачим (если соблюдается конвенция именования).

```
$user->roles()->attach([
    1 => ['expires' => $expires],
    2 => ['expires' => $expires]
]);
```

Ну и ещу - вот это не имеет смысла - `$lastAdded = Books::all()->last()->id;`, потому что вот тут - `$book->fill($request->all())->save();` мы уже имеет все данные. Попробуйте после этого сделать `dd($book->id);`